# Entity Framework conectado a una base de datos PosgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, docker

pues estoy intentando conectarme a una BD PostgreSQL (montada con docker en local) desde una aplicación web en ASP.Net Core 3.1

Estoy siguiendo los pasos de https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/

Mi modelo es este:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace RazorPagesCharacters.Models
{
    public class Character
    {
        public Guid id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
        public string hierarchy { get; set; }
        public string organization { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    }
}
```

En el archivo startup tengo el ConfigureService así:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddDbContext<RazorPagesCharactersContext>(options =>                   options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("RazorPagesCharactersContext")    
));
}
```

El archivo de mi DBContext es este:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RazorPagesCharacters.Models;

namespace RazorPagesCharacters.Data
{
    public class RazorPagesCharactersContext : DbContext
    {
        public RazorPagesCharactersContext (DbContextOptions<RazorPagesCharactersContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<RazorPagesCharacters.Models.Character> Character { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=127.0.0.1:5436;Database=Ejemplo-db;Username=postgres;Password=postgres");

    }
}
```

El ultimo paso sería escribir el siguiente código en la terminal:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Host=127.0.0.1:5436;Database=Ejemplo-db;Username=postgres;Password=postgres" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): Host desconocido.
at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName)
at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.AllocateLong(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.    <<Open>g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Scaffolding.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseModelFactory.Create(DbConnection dbConnection, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
at     Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Scaffolding.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
at     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.Scaff    oldModel(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions databaseOptions,     ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions)
at     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(S    tring provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String     outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1     tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Host desconocido.
```

No se si es que no he hecho algo bien en plan... la bd es Ejemplo-vd pero dentro hay varias tablas y solo quiero acceder a la tabla characters, y no haya especificado esto bien, o es cosa de permisos....

a esta bd me puedo conectar sin problemas desde otra application, asi que acceder puedo accederla...
A ver si alguno me puede dar la clave de lo que esta mal aqui...

Gracias!

Comment: lo que te recomiendo es crear un usuario diferente  a postgres

Comment: que tal si nos muestra el comando de docker para ejecutar tu imagen, tu programa esta con Dockerfile?? si es asi debes conectarlo con el nombre de la contenedor

Comment: Al final decidí usar querys string en vez de entity... Gracias por vuestra ayuda!